# How to generate XYZ tiles in QGis with extent?

Tags: qgis, mbtiles, xyz, xyz-tiles

I have a huge mbtile of my country. I have marked only roads from this file in my QGis project. Now I'm trying to export only data related to a boundary(the city I live in). So in the extent I put my boundary, like this: `91.733937,91.929579,22.196513,22.478441`

But in the output folder I only get an empty tile, doesn't matter which zoom I pick, it only returns one tile.

First I tried to clip the mbtile, but that didn't work properly, so I'm trying this approach now. I tried clipping with `tilelive-copy`.

[image: qgis generate xyz tiles with extent]

Comment: Can you pick an extent boundary from the screen using the small select arrow?

Comment: If you select the small arrow (triangle) button the dropdown menu allows you to "Draw on Map Canvas".  Do that and then change the numbers to match the boundary that you want.    Mine also provided the EPSG code for the current map. 
   ->  13479969.7701,13480077.6431,309712.0164,309798.9529 [EPSG:6494]